# how to count the result

Tags: command-line

How to count the result? when you write a command and some result appears. any way to 
count them. For example If I want how many result I have for applications which have python word .

```
dpkg -l | grep python
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of grep, you can simply use the `-c` option

```
dpkg -l | grep -c python
```

From `man grep`

```
   -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
          for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
          below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
```

More generally, you can pipe command output to the `wc` command e.g.

```
 dpkg -l | grep python | wc -l
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is to use a for loop and a variable that counts the elements:

```
for i in `dpkg -l | grep python`; do let elements=elements+1; done; echo $elements
```

You can change the text inside the `` to adapt it to other commands.

Comment: This is really inefficient. use `grep -c` instead

Comment: Yes, but it's a more generic way if the command that you want to count the output of it's not grep.

Comment: like your way but I think yours sum of all python word on the result but my question is not that how ever thanks for your cooperation

Comment: I upvoted the other answer anyway, it seems a better sollution :)